# Initializer For Conditional Binding Must Have Optional Type, not CLPlacemark

Tags: ios, swift

Noob programmer here.

I'm trying to become a good programmer with the help of the internet. So, I subscribed to Rob Percivals iOS class. I'm having trouble with this bit of my code. Must've been a recent update that's making it fail on my system although it is the same code as his.

```
CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(userLocation) { (placemarks, error) in

        if (error != nil) {

            print(error)

        } else {

        if let p = CLPlacemark(placemark: placemarks![0] as! CLPlacemark) {

            print(p)

            }
        }            
    }
}
```

Please try to put it in baby english if possible guys. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`placemarks` is of type `[CLPlacemark]?`. Therefore you should try something like the following:

```
if let placemarks = placemarks {
    if let p0 = placemarks.first {
        print (p0)
    }
}
```

Don't use `!`. Use `if let` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The error message just says that the initializer `CLPlacemark(placemark:)` does never return a `nil` value so reduce the code and even remove the type casting, because according to the signature `[CLPlacemark]?`is returned. Optional binding is not needed because if the error is `nil` the array is guaranteed to exist.

```
...
} else {
   if !placemarks!.isEmpty {
      let p = CLPlacemark(placemark: placemarks![0])
      print(p)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend taking it a step further with a guard statement, and being a little more verbose with the variable name p... Guard is a good way to exit from the current flow without cluttering your code with if statements, especially since the 'if let' optional unwrapping syntax came around.

```
CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(userLocation) { (placemarks, error) in

    guard error == nil else {
        print(error)
        return
    }

    if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
         let currentPlacemark = CLPlacemark(placemark: placemark)
         print(currentPlacemark)
    }
}
```